# proc_dir_entry warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I'm trying to build a kernel module, but while compiling it in a make file I got some errors which I can't solve. This is the code for the module:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/list.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>

#include "sar_main.h"

#define PROCFS_NAME "sarlkm"

char procfs_buffer[PROCFS_MAX_SIZE];

static unsigned long procfs_buffer_size = 0;

struct proc_dir_entry *proc_file_entry;


int procfile_read(char *buffer, char **buffer_location, off_t offset, int buffer_length, int *eof, void *data){
    int ret;

    printk(KERN_INFO "procfile_read (/proc/%s) called \n",  PROCFS_NAME);

    if (offset > 0){
        ret = 0;
    }
    else{
        copy_to_user(procfs_buffer, buffer, procfs_buffer_size);
        ret = procfs_buffer_size;
    }
    return ret;
}

int procfile_write(struct file *file, const char *buffer, unsigned long count, void *data){

    procfs_buffer_size = count;
    if (procfs_buffer_size > PROCFS_MAX_SIZE){
        procfs_buffer_size = PROCFS_MAX_SIZE;
    }
    if ( copy_from_user(procfs_buffer, buffer, procfs_buffer_size)){
        return -EFAULT;
    }
    return procfs_buffer_size;
}

static const struct file_operations proc_file_ops = {
    .read = procfile_read,
    .write = procfile_write,
};


static int __init sar_init(void)
{
    proc_file_entry = proc_create(PROCFS_NAME, 0644, NULL, &proc_file_ops);

    if (proc_file_entry == NULL){
        remove_proc_entry(PROCFS_NAME, NULL);
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Error: Unable to create proc file");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }


    printk(KERN_INFO "proc/%s successfully created", PROCFS_NAME);
    return 0;
}

static void __exit sar_cleanup(void)
{
    remove_proc_entry(PROCFS_NAME, NULL);
    printk(KERN_INFO "proc/%s deleted", PROCFS_NAME);
}

module_init(sar_init);
module_exit(sar_cleanup);

MODULE_AUTHOR(DRIVER_AUTHOR);
MODULE_DESCRIPTION(DRIVER_DESC);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

So I get the error while defining the struct proc_file_ops. I haven't been able to find a definition for the read and write functions of proc_dir_entry, but I have found some examples on the web that have used the exact same statements that I've used. Can anybody explain why I get this warning and what to do about it please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Root cause

Probably examples you found are intended for some different kernel version (other than you use). Internal kernel API varies from version to version. See
[Documentation/stable_api_nonsense.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/stable_api_nonsense.txt) for details. The general advice is to look into exactly your kernel sources for code examples. For example see how proc API implemented in [kernel/time/timer_stats.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time/timer_stats.c) (in your kernel code, of course).

### Why warnings

Your signatures of `procfile_read()` and `procfile_write()` functions must be the same as in `struct file_operations`:

```c
ssize_t (*read) (struct file *, char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);
ssize_t (*write) (struct file *, const char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);
```

But you have next signatures instead:

```c
int procfile_read(char *buffer, char **buffer_location, off_t offset,
                  int buffer_length, int *eof, void *data)
int procfile_write(struct file *file, const char *buffer,
                   unsigned long count, void *data)
```

You probably need to double check the actual signatures in `struct file_operations` for your kernel version.

### Example code insights

Also you may notice that `.read` callback need to be set like that (in new kernel versions):

```
.read = seq_read,
```

And actual reading should be done via `.open` callback:

```
.open = tstats_open,
```

In open function you need to call your actual show function, like this:

```
static int tstats_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
    return single_open(filp, tstats_show, NULL);
}
```

And show function should have signature like this:

```
static int tstats_show(struct seq_file *m, void *v)
```

For complete example see [kernel/time/timer_stats.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time/timer_stats.c) in your kernel.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I don't know that much C to be honest, this is just for an OS class, so please don't be too harsh if the questions are a little too basic. I'm still not really sure what the problem is, is it the return type of the functions? What exactly is the type of read in struct file_operations, is that a pointer to a function? Or do the arguments of the functions in file_operations not match those in procfile_read? How can I check the signatures in struct file_operations for my kernel version?

Comment: Look, the problem you are facing is more complicated than you think. You can't just simply fix your example you found in web. You have 2 possible solutions to your problem: 1. Use exactly the same kernel version code as in example you found. **OR** 2. Completely rewrite all the code for your kernel version code. And code you found for another kernel version can't be easily adopted, kernel API changed too much. So I encourage you to use some code that creates /proc files from your kernel code base as an example. Take a look at `kernel/time/timer_stats.c` file (as I proposed in my answer).

Comment: Answering to your questions in your comment: the problem is not only return type of read/write functions, it's the whole [function signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature) (return type, arguments types, arguments count): the whole signature should be the same as required by `.read`/`.write` fields of `struct file_operations`. You can find this structure definition at [include/linux/fs.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/fs.h#L1538) file (again, you should use file from **your** kernel sources).

Comment: And yes, read/write fields in that structure are pointers to functions (called [callback functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29#C)).

Comment: To check read/write function signatures in your kernel -- just look at `struct file_operations` definition at `include/linux/fs.h` file, you will see `(*read)` and `(*write)` fields. Make sure that your read/write functions have the same signature as in that structure.

Comment: **BUT**, even if you will managed to fix those warnings and build your example -- it **won't** work. Such straight-forward approach doesn't work here, because not only signatures were changed in new kernel versions, but also the way the whole thing should be designed. See **Example code insights** section in my original answer for details. The bottom line: you should use some code from your kernel as an example, and not some stuff found in web.

Comment: Ok thanks so much for your help, really appreciate it. I will try to do what you said and maybe come back later if I can't get this to work myself. Thanks again.